# Basin of attraction of a fixed point

Tags: dynamical-systems, basins-of-attraction

I want to find the **basin of attraction** of a fixed point.

For example, I have $f(x)=\frac 1{x+1}$, whose fixed points are $\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Now, I must create a neighborhood around the $x$ point that would consist of all points around it that would attract to it. How can I figure out the radius of a neighborhood?

Answer (score 4):

For the endpoints $a,b$ of the immediate basin of attraction of an attracting fixed point, the possibilities are:

1. $\pm \infty$.
2. A singularity (i.e. where $f$ is undefined).
3. A repelling fixed point.
4. $(a,b)$ is a $2$-cycle, i.e. $f(a) = b$ and $f(b) = a$.

   Take the closest of these possibiities on each side of your fixed point.

Comment: I have two fixed points, so do you mean on each side of each fixed point?

Comment: One fixed point is attracting, the other is repelling.   A repelling fixed point has no basin of attraction.

Comment: I found the basin of attraction (through graphing trial-and-error) to be $(-1,\infty)$. Is it possible to prove this rigorously?

Comment: Yes.  From what I wrote above, the candidates for endpoints (for the attracting fixed point $(-1+\sqrt{5})/2$ are $-\infty$, the repelling fixed point $(-1-\sqrt{5})/2$, the singularity $-1$, and $+\infty$ (there are no real $2$-cycles).  The closest candidate to the left of the attracting fixed point is $-1$, the closest to the right is $+\infty$.  So the immediate basin of attraction is $(-1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Note that this is the **immediate** basin of attraction, not the full basin of attraction: there are also points not in $(-1,+\infty)$ which are attracted to the attracting fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

You have four possible regions here:

1. the region to the right of the right fixed point $(x > \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$,
2. the region between the fixed points $(\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2} < x < \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$
3. the region to the left of the singularity $(x < -1)$.
4. the region between the left fixed point and the singularity $(-1 < x < \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2})$

If you find the derivative in these three regions, you should be able to see what the basin is for each point (if it exists).

Comment: You forgot about the singularity.